# How to get screenshot of current page in asp.net.

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I want to save screenshot of the current page ( full page with scroll) and save it as an image or pdf .

Comment: Please share the code you have tried yet.

Comment: I haven't  try any code for this , I want just simple screen shot of any web page in asp.net .

Comment: *I haven't try any code for this* ok, I suggest you to go and code. Come with a specific problem with some code. Stackoverflow is not "Get me the code" kind of site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) js library to take a screen shot and then use canvas in javascript to download/save.

HTML

```
<button id="save-img">Download</button>
```

JS/jQuery

```
$("#save-img").click(function () {
    html2canvas(document.body, {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            document.location = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        }
    });
});
```

Or read this [article](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Capture-Screenshot-Snapshot-Image-of-Website-Web-Page-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx) if you want to achieve this in asp.net using DataVisualization.

Hope that helps.